# How can I get this easyhook demo run?

Tags: easyhook

I'm trying to get this easyhook demo run on my computer, but don't know how.
I have little experience in windows programming.
They have a tutorial on easyhook in this
http://easyhook.codeplex.com/downloads/get/61179
At first they present a demo, but I don't know how to build this project.
They said
We need a host process which injects the library and displays
file accesses.
I don't how this is done. I guess I need to open a project in Visual Studio? Can someone teach me step-by-step?Thanks!